# What is the difference between Integer Quadratic Programming versus Mixed Integer Quadratic Programming?

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization

I am new to the optimization problem of Quadratic programming.
In equation $8$ of [this paper](http://acberg.com/papers/berg_correspondence_cvpr.pdf), there is an equation:

> $$\min \operatorname{cost} (x) = x' H x +c' H x \quad \text{subject to,}  \tag{8}  \\
> Ax=b, \quad x\in\{0,1\}^n$$

The authors state that this is an `'Integer Quadratic Programming (IQP)'` formula.

Alternatively, in [this other website](https://tomopt.com/docs/models/tomlab_models007.php), there is the following equation which is described as a '`Mixed Integer Quadratic Programming` (`MIQP`)' formulation:

> $$\min\limits_x f(x) = \frac12 x^T F x +c^T x$$

From my perspective, both of the equations shown above are similar, with the only difference being that the `MIQP` formula has '$1/2$' included in it.

1. I am looking for an explanation on the differences between the `IQP` and `MIQP` and in particular what the '$1/2$' represents in `MIQP`.
2. In addition, I am interested to apply quadratic programming to the assignment problem, thus, looking for any insight into which should be used (i.e., `IQP` vs. `MIQP`) and when.

Comment: IQP implies all variables can only be integers. MIQP implies some can only be integers while others can be real numbers.

Comment: @RohitPandey do you know why the '1/2' term is added to the MIQP formulation?

Comment: Don't know for sure, but its generally just a scaling factor so that taking derivative cancels the $2$ out. Some people tend to include it, others don't. Doesn't affect the optimization problem in spirit and I highly doubt it has anything to do with the problem being MIQP.

Comment: good explanation.

Comment: @user121 The scaling factor of $1/2$ is the same as the one you'll find in some definitions of quadratic forms: for example, see this [history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form#Integral_quadratic_forms) section of the Wikipedia article on integral quadratic forms.